# Find this US city

Tags: geography

AZ -> +1

TN -> +1

-4 <- NV

-6 <- PA

GA -> +4

What US city is this? (2 words)

Clue:

> Microsoft

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The city is

> BATON ROUGE

I got it by

> Take all the combinations of two letters in order AA, AB, AC, ... ZX, ZY, ZZ.
>  Clue AZ -> +1 means to move forward one in the list from AZ, which would be BA
>  Same goes for the other clues, with the negative numbers meaning to go backwards in the list, giving us BA, TO, NR, OU, GE as the new pairs.
>  The clue didn't help as I associate Microsoft with Washington.  I didn't know they had anything special going on in Louisiana.

Comment: Microsoft was a hint because of Microsoft Excel, where the columns follow this pattern.

Comment: @PhilippeOlivier Why the arrows, and why do negatives go right to left?

Comment: @xnor Now that I think about it I should not have put the +/- signs, but just the arrows. The plan was to make you think (take the first line for example) that the US city had something to do with a state East of Arizona.